# Issue in multiple buttons in Html.BeginForm in ASP.net MVC4

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i am doing my project in asp.net MVC4 using c#

I am trying to select a photo and save  that image in a folder,

for that i have an html Begin form

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("ImageReplace", "Member", new { imgid = @Model.Id }, FormMethod.Post,new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
  { 
     <input type="text" name="fake_section" class="fake_section"><button class="fake_section">Choose Photo</button>
     <input type="file" style="display:none;" name="file" id="file" value="Choose Photo" accept="image/png,image/jpeg" /> 
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
   }
```

And i have a controller also

```
  public ActionResult ImageReplace(HttpPostedFileBase file,int imgid)
    {
        ......
    }
```

For styling and validating the form (only select the gif and jpeg files) i use the following jquery

```
 $('.fake_section').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#file').trigger('click');
});

$('#file').change(function (e) {
    var filename = $(this).val();
    var ext = filename.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();

    if ($.inArray(ext, ['gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg']) == -1) {
        alert('not valid!');
    }
    else {
        $('input[name="fake_section"]').val(filename);
    }
});
```

[image]

My problem is that **when click to choose the photo it is directly go to Controller Action without selecting photo**

Comment: Does changing the button to `<input type="button" class="fake_section" value="Choose Photo"/>` help?

Comment: Now it is not go to Controller .. but not selecting the image

Comment: By `not selecting the image` do you mean file chooser dialog is not opening?

Comment: Do you have proper version of jquery included? You might also try `$('#file').click();`

Comment: ya i solve that problem .. thank you for helping me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that button type is missig. 
Look at this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CJf9f/

```
<button class="fake_section" type="button">Choose Photo</button>
```

Comment: This just helped me with my issue: multiple buttons within form, all were submitting form instead of triggering expected actions.